# Running processes in batch on grid engine using map_async()

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am trying to test my parallelised code on Sun Grid Engine. My code seems to work fine on my local linux machine, however I am limited on local due to the small number of CPUs. My code is interfaced to some other code which runs some more elaborate calculations based of some inputs my code calculates. I aim to run approx. 7000 processes in chunks of 31 using the 32 processors that are directly available to me on the grid engine without submission to the queueing system. My code does some stuff using these 32 processors and then submits a job to the queuing system using subprocess.Popen([qsub submission_script.sh], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE), each of these jobs submitted to the queue require 8 processors, each with 6GB of variable memory. Using Pool and map_async I can submit batches of 31 jobs to the queue using my script until all the 7000 inputs have run. My code then waits for the jobs in the queue to terminate, extracts some data from them, and then based on this it generates another batch of jobs to be submitted to the queue again (so there are 2 batches of submission for each of the 7000 initial jobs).

```
def run(gridPoint):
    """Takes each geometry and an index for each grid point and runs the series
       of calculations specified by the user for either quantum chemistry code
       in parallel. Data for each grid point is sorted in global arrays according
       to the index."""
    index, geom = gridPoint

    if inputs['code'] == 'molpro':

        [workdirSPE, inputSPE] = molpro.setupSPE(inputs, geom, pwd, index)
        [normalTermination, outputSPE] = util.runCalculation(inputs['hpc'], molproKeys, pwd, workdirSPE, inputSPE, submissionScript, index) # Submit first round of calculations to grid engine and wait
        if normalTermination:  # If normal termination extract some data
            data.energiesExtract(workdirSPE+outputSPE, inputs['spe'], molproKeys['energy_regex'],
                                  molproKeys['cas_prog'], index)

            if inputs['nacme'] == 'yes':  # Then submit another round of calculations to the grid engine based off initial ones - My script just stops here on the grid engine - although is fine on my local machine.
                [nacmeWorkdir, nacmeInput, daxes] = molpro.nacmeSetup(inputs, geom, workdirSPE, index)
                [nacmeNormalTermination, nacmeOutput] = util.runCalculation(inputs['hpc'], molproKeys, pwd, nacmeWorkdir, nacmeInput, submissionScript, index) 
                if nacmeNormalTermination:
                    data.nacmeExtract(nacmeWorkdir+nacmeOutput, molproKeys['nacme_regex'], index, daxes)
                else:
                    data.nacmes[:, :, :, index] = 'NaN'

            if inputs['grad'] == 'yes':
                [gradWorkdir, gradInput] = molpro.gradientSetup(inputs, geom, workdirSPE, index)
                [gradNormalTermination, gradOutput] = util.runCalculation(inputs['hpc'], molproKeys, pwd, gradWorkdir, gradInput, submissionScript, index)  # Submit third round of calcualtions to grid engine.
                if gradNormalTermination:
                    data.gradExtractMolpro(gradWorkdir+gradOutput, molproKeys['grad_regex'], molproKeys['numerical'], index)
                else:
                    data.grads[:, :, :, index] = 'NaN'

        else:
            data.energies[index, :] = 'NaN'
            if inputs['nacme'] == 'yes':
                data.nacmes[:, :, :, index] = 'NaN'
            if inputs['grad'] == 'yes':
                data.grads[:, :, :, index] = 'NaN'


    elif inputs['code'] == 'molcas':   # TO DO
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pwd = os.getcwd()  # parent dir for all calculations
    listGeom = coordinateGenerator(refGeom)  # Generate coordinates
    if inputs['code'] == 'molpro':  # All possible state couplings
        couplings = molpro.stateCouplings(inputs['states'][-1])
    elif inputs['code'] == 'molcas':
        pass
    pmanager = setup.ProccessManager()  # Force global mem sharing for ouput data
    pmanager.start()
    data = setup.datastore(refGeom, inputs['states'][-1], couplings, len(listGeom), pmanager)
    cpuCount = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2
    runPool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpuCount)
    runPool.map_async(run, [(k, v) for k, v in enumerate(listGeom)]) # listGeom contains 7000 inputs to be run in batches of n (where n=cpuCount).
    runPool.close()
    runPool.join()
    np.save('ENERGIES.npy', data.energies)  # Extract data
    if inputs['nacme'] == 'yes':
        np.save('NACMES.npy', data.nacmes)
    if inputs['grad'] == 'yes':
```

The function that does the submission to the grid engine is as follows,

```
def runCalculation(system: str, codeKeys: dict, pwd: str, workdir: str, inputfile: str, submitscript: str, index: int):
    '''Submits calculations to either a local linux OS, or a HPC running eithers Sun Grid Engine or PBS Pro.                                                                                                                                                                               
       Waits for calculation to finish running and then returns True if it terminated with no errors. '''
    outputfile = inputfile.split('.')[0]+'.out'
    os.chdir('%s' % (workdir))

    if system == 'local':  #  Run calculation and wait for termination in each case
        runLocal(codeKeys, inputfile)
    elif system == 'sun grid engine':
        gridEngineScript = setup_submit_script(submitscript, inputfile, index)
        qsub(gridEngineScript)
    elif system == 'pbs':
        pass

    terminationCode = calculationTermination(codeKeys, outputfile)  #  check normal termination
    os.chdir(pwd)
    return terminationCode


def subprocess_cmd(command, return_stdout):  # Used for submission using qsub to grid engine.
    ''' Returns output for a shell command. '''
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    if return_stdout:
        return(proc_stdout)
```

I have omitted some functions here to simplify, but basically each call to `runCalculation()` submits to the grid engine using subprocess.Popen(). At the second submission I just get the error of `RuntimeError: can't start new thread`, I am not sure why as `ulimit -u` tells me I have a limit of 200 threads, and I am only running these calculations in batches of 31 when I have 32 processors directly available and the heavy lifting which is done by the programme I am interfacing to is submitted the queue. Checking the processes I have running using `ps -fLu [uid]` shows there are no extra unexpected processes running. Reducing the number of calculations to be run to 31, or running my python script using as few as 10 processors still results in this issue.

If anyone has any insight into what is going on that would be great. Thanks!